# .htaccess the result adds the query string that I want to hide

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've written this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^news(/([0-9]+)?)?$ news_list.php?pag=$2 [L]
```

Expecting to catch those links

```
www.example.com/news
www.example.com/news/
www.example.com/news/1
```

Works fine, but the problem is that when I navigate to `www.example.com/news`, in the url bar appears the query string : `www.example.com/news/?pag=`

That is exactly what I want to hide.

---

By the moment I had to add, before this line, a specific rule to catch just this case:

RewriteRule ^news?$ news_list.php [L]

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. In the file system there is a folder named "news". This may conflict with the rule.